# Paramiko Can't get xwindow info

Tags: python, linux, x11, paramiko

I want to get X window information by using Paramiko, and run this python code, can't get stdout.

*code & result*

```py
# define ssh_manager
.
.
ssh_manager.exec_command("export DISPLAY=:0")
stdin, stdout, stderr= ssh_manager.exec_command("sudo xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname")
print(stdout.readlines())

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_6.2p2)
INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (password) successful!
[]
```

but it works on `localhost`.

Comment: i changed "DISPLAY=:0 sudo xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname", and it worked.

Comment: If you know the solution, please post it as an answer.